# How to set input value base on useState in react-admin v4?

Tags: react-admin

I'm moving in react-admin v4.
In my v3 (3.19.11), I have a TextInput with an initialValue equals to state.
By default this state is an empty string and when I complete some other fields, it's updated and the value of the TextInput too.

In v4 initialValue doesn't exist anymore and is replaced by defaultValue but it seems that doesn't work the same way.
I would like to know if there is a simple way to do the same thing than v3 without to create a custom form with useForm/useController.

I tried to do that with a TextInput, a TextField and a native input.
My issue is that either I don't have the input value updated, or it's updated but the input is not submitted in the form.

Code example in my v3 :

```
const [channelName, setChannelName] = useState<string>('');
const [partnerName, setPartnerName] = useState<string>('');
const [campaignName, setCampaignName] = useState<string>('');

useEffect(() => {
    const fillCampaignName = () => {
      const campaignValues: string[] = [];

      campaignValues.push(channelName, partnerName);

      const campaignValuesString = campaignValues
        .filter((item) => item !== '')
        .join('_');

      setCampaignName(campaignValuesString);
    };

    fillCampaignName();
  }, [channelName, partnerName]);

<Create {...props}>
  <SimpleForm>
    <AutocompleteInput variant="standard" source="channel" choices={channels} onChange={(channel: string) => setChannelName(channel)} />
    <AutocompleteInput variant="standard" source="partner" choices={partners} onChange={(partner: string) => setPartnerName(partner)} />
    <TextInput disabled source="name" variant="standard" label="Campaign name" initialValue={campaignName} />
  </SimpleForm>
</Create>
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `defaultValue` instead of `initialValue`?

https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Upgrade.html#inputs

Comment: It's what I did but doesn't work, it seems that doesn't work the same way (react-final-form vs react-hook-form)

Answer (score 0):

Use useFormContext then you can setValue programatically.

```
import { useFormContext } from 'react-hook-form';

const MyForm = (props) => {
  const { setValue } = useFormContext();
  useEffect(() => {
    setValue('date', props.date)
    }, [props.date])
  }

  return (
    <DateTimeInput source="date"/>
  )
}
```